# Trying to read data from text data and build objects from that

Tags: java, arrays

```java
public void getAnimalsFromTextFile() throws IOException {
    String file = "C:\\Users\\nikit\\OneDrive\\Desktop\\animals.txt";
    BufferedReader inFile = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
    String line;
    int cnt = 0;
    while ((line = inFile.readLine()) != null) {
        StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(line,"");
        if(st.hasMoreTokens()) {
            String line1 = st.nextToken();
            StringTokenizer st1 = new StringTokenizer(line1, " ");
            while (st1.hasMoreTokens()) {
                String att = st1.nextToken();
                strings.add(att);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This text file is:

```
Jackie Jack Boston
Marty Bird California
Donald Duck Netherlands
```

I want to build 3 `Animal` objects from this file, like:

```java
Animal animal =  new Animal(Jackie, Jack, Boston);
```

Then add them to array.

In the and I want to store the animals objects in array.

Answer (score 1):

You wrote in your question:

> I want to build 3 animal objects

That means you want a class named `Animal` which has three attributes, i.e.

```java
public class Animal {
    private String first;
    private String second;
    private String third;
}
```

Note that I could not ascertain, from your question, what each attrbiute represents and therefore I named them `first`, `second` and `third`.

Now you want to write a constructor for your class:

```java
public Animal(String first, String second, String third) {
    this.first = first;
    this.second = second;
    this.third = third;
}
```

You also wrote in your question:

> I want to store the animals objects in array

An array has a fixed size which you provide when you declare it. Since you are reading from a file, you probably don't know the size, hence probably better to use a [List](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/List.html).

When reading from a file in Java, after you have finished reading the file, you should close it. Since Java 7, there is [try-with-resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html).

Also since Java 7 there is class `Files` which is part of [NIO.2](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/fileio.html).

`StringTokenizer` is a legacy class. New code should use method `split` of class `java.lang.String`.

Here is sample code that achieves what you want.

```java
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Animal {
    private String first;
    private String second;
    private String third;

    public Animal(String first, String second, String third) {
        this.first = first;
        this.second = second;
        this.third = third;
    }

    public static void getAnimalsFromTextFile() throws IOException {
        List<Animal> animals = new ArrayList<>();
        Path path = Paths.get("animals.txt");
        try (BufferedReader inFile = Files.newBufferedReader(path)) {
            String line = inFile.readLine();
            while (line != null) {
                String[] strings = line.split(" ");
                Animal animal = new Animal(strings[0], strings[1], strings[2]);
                animals.add(animal);
                line = inFile.readLine();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Alternatively, you could use [streams](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/architect-streams-pt2.html) which was introduced in Java 8.

```java
public static void getAnimalsFromTextFile() throws IOException {
    Path path = Paths.get("animals.txt");
    try (Stream<String> stream = Files.lines(path)) {
        List<Animal> animals = stream.map(line -> line.split(" "))
                                     .map(array -> new Animal(array[0], array[1], array[2]))
                                     .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a class that holds three animals, this will be the

```
class Animal {
    
    private String animal1; 
    private String animal2; 
    private String animal3;
    public Animal(String animal1, String animal2, String animal3) {
        super();
        this.animal1 = animal1;
        this.animal2 = animal2;
        this.animal3 = animal3;
    }
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Animal [animal1=" + animal1 + ", animal2=" + animal2 + ", animal3=" + animal3 + "]";
    }
}
```

**Inside your loop (while reading the file)**

1. Split the current line with space (`" "`) and get an array of elements.
2. Pass each array element respectively to your animal constructor.
3. Once you have the object assign it to the array with the index `cnt`.

   public class AnimalManager {

   ```
   public static void main(String[] args) {


       try (BufferedReader inFile = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("animals.txt"));) {

           String line;
           int cnt = 0;
           Animal[] animalArray = new Animal[10];

           while ((line = inFile.readLine()) != null) {

               String animalsInLine[] = line.split(" ");
               animalArray[cnt++] = new Animal(animalsInLine[0], animalsInLine[1], animalsInLine[2]);
           }

           System.out.println(java.util.Arrays.toString(animalArray));
       } catch (IOException e) {
           System.out.println("Error while file handling : " + e.getMessage());
       }
   }
   ```